# MobileFirst: Back-end service discovery wizard not appearing - single wsdl with multiple xsd files

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

I have a wsdl & multiple xsd files.

When I copy them inside the **services** folder of a MobileFirst project. Then it does not show/detect them inside the services folder. It shows as empty folder when viewing in `Project Explorer` view. However it does show wsdl & xsds files when viewing through `Package Explorer`.

I want to **run** the `Back-end service discovery wizard` to generate the adapter functions, rather than manually typing the SOAP messages in adapter functions.

Currently it is not showing the option of **Back-end service discovery wizard**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need to copy the wsdl and xsd files into the services folder. You should be able to run the Back-end service discovery wizard off the services folder and then point to those files on your file system.

Comment: +1 You can also place your WSDLs and XSDs in some other folder in your workspace and import from workspace when using the discovery wizard.

Answer (score 0):

The project explorer view only shows elements under the services folder that are representations of the underlying service model (as defined in the service descriptor xml files).  It does not show the xml files themselves or any other file types, but just shows nodes that represent a service model node.  This was done only for the project explorer view.  You can view the service descriptor xml files and any other file types in other viewers such as the navigator viewer or package explorer.  It is assumed that the only files that would ever be in the services folder would be the service descriptor xml files.  It is not necessary that you put your files under this folder.